# using std::transform the final vector remains empty

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I am not using std::transform often, however I found it very useful and I am starting replacing some for loops with this algorithm.

What is wrong here? I want to keep all the elements of the vector vec that have code > 100. I would expect to have a new std::vector with 3 elements: 133, 144 and 155. But after the algorithm the size is 0. What is wrong?

```
 TEST_CASE("testing trasf1", "[tras1]") {

    std::vector<Test2> vec {
            {1,1},
            {3,3},
            {11,11},
            {12,12},
            {133,133},
            {19,19},
            {21,21},
            {22,22},
            {23,23},
            {144,144},
            {155,155}

    };

    std::vector<uint32_t> final_v {};
    final_v.reserve(vec.size());

    transform(begin(vec), end(vec), begin(final_v), [] (const Test2& elem) {
        if ( elem.getCode() > 100)
            return elem.getCode();
    });

    //REQUIRE(final.size() == 3);

    cout << final_v.size() << endl;

    for (const auto i : final_v) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dont use final, it is keyword. Second, call resize instead of reserve on final. Or use back_inserter. You are putting values to empty final.

Comment: Your lambda doesn't seem to declare its return type. I think it should be `[] (const Test2& elem) -> int {...};`.

Comment: @rafix07 addressed your comment

Comment: Your lambda only returns a defined value if `elem.getCode() > 100`. Remember that a lambda works the same way as any other function, all code paths must return a value. `std::transform` will always output exactly as many elements as are in the input, so there's no way for `final.size() == 3`. I don't _think_ (open to correction) there's an `std` algorithm that does a filter and transform in a single step, so you'll either have to use a loop or do it in two steps.

Comment: @Stu or use a range library

Comment: @Stu right, I am trying to filter AND transform here …

Comment: @Stu I don't think so either. With ranges and views in C++20, this would be pretty easy. For transform one could adapt `back_inserter` with as some kind of `optional_inserter` that gets `std::optional<T>` and inserts if it is not nullopt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform` doesn't insert elements into the output sequence, it just writes to the `*iter` and increments the iterator.

If you want to insert to the sequence, use `std::back_inserter(final)` as the output iterator.

Alternatively, call `final.resize(vec.size())` first, to set the output vector to the correct size. Note that this will intialize the vector elements to zero, so for large vectors will incur a noticeable time overhead.

Comment: If I call resize instead of reserve the final vector has 22 elements (2*initial size)

Comment: `resize` would also mean that the vector contains a lot of trash data in the above example, which would have to be filtered out if OP only wants a vector with these three elements. `reserve` + `back_inserter` seems clearly superior if I don't miss anything. Edit: Nevermind, `transform` always outputs the same number of elements.

Comment: If you call `resize` *and* use `back_inserter` then you will get twice as many elements. Do one or the other.

Comment: @Captain Nemo it is either `resize` and `begin(final_v)` or `reserve` and `back_inserter` NOT `resize` and `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing filter and transform in one operation:

```cpp
template<class Container>
struct optional_inserter_iterator: std::back_insert_iterator //convenience
{
    using std::back_insert_iterator::*;
    optional_inserter_iterator(Container &c) : std::back_insert_iterator(c)
    {}

    optional_inserter_iterator & operator=(std::optional<Container::value_type> &&opt)
    {
        if(opt)
            std::back_insert_iterator::operator=(*std::move(opt))
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Use this in transform and let your lambda return an optional

(untested)

EDIT: There are some reasons not to inherit from `std::back_insert_iterator`. If someone is interested in a really correct version, I can do one.