# Transforming an OutputIterator before inserting into a container

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, stdvector

I have a function defined as follows:

```
template <class Iter> Iter generate(Iter);
```

where Iter is expected to behave like an OutputIterator, and the returned iterator is one element after the last element generated (similar to the third argument to `std::transform`)

I'd like to call this function, apply a predicate to each item generated, and then transform the remaining elements to a different type. I know I can do this as follows:

```
std::vector<some_type> generated_raw;
generate(std::back_inserter(generated_raw));
generated_raw.erase(std::remove_if(generated_raw.begin(), generated_raw.end(), predicate));
std::vector<other_type> generated;
std::transform(generated_raw.begin(), generated_raw.end(), std::back_inserter(generated), transform);
```

where predicate and transform are both functions.

However, this is inefficient as it involves an intermediate container in which every generated element is stored - even the ones which will later be rejected by the erase/remove_if call. Is there better way of doing this?

Comment: You would need a custom output iterator for that... [boost::transform_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) might help as model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```cpp
template<class Iter, class Pred>
struct PredicatedIter {
    Iter it;
    Pred pr;

    PredicatedIter& operator=(const typename Iter::Container::value_type &v) {
        if(pr(v)) {
            it = v;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    PredicatedIter& operator=(typename Iter::Container::value_type &&v) {
        if(pr(v)) {
            it = std::move(v);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // no-ops as in back_insert_iterator    
    PredicatedIter& operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    PredicatedIter& operator++(int) {
        return *this;
    }

    PredicatedIter& operator*() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

PS: I did something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068682/using-stdtransform-the-final-vector-remains-empty/59069640#59069640) and reworked my answer [here](https://github.com/Nicholas42/Cpp-Bits-and-Pieces/tree/master/optional_inserter).